# Django Mailbox Query

Tags: django

So I am writing a page that gets the threads between the authenticated user and other users and i'm not sure on the most efficient way of doing so. In theory:

- It needs to get all records where **user_from** or **user_to** is the authenticated user
- Order by most recent
- Obviously only needs one message between **user_from** and **user_to**

I'm guessing it would be best to use a group by to get only the one mail and i'm not sure how i'd go about using two fields for the grouping. Heres what I have so far:

```
Message.objects.filter(Q(user_to=request.user) | Q(user_from=request.user)).order_by('-sent')
```

Is this possible in Django? Another option is to get the unique messages to/from other users. I am okay with not showing a message

Comment: Yeah.. just add `.distinct()` clause, and you have what you need.

Comment: That didn't do anything